# rocksdb build failed in Clion at MacOS

Tags: makefile, cmake, clion, rocksdb

My environment:

```
macOS 10.14
Clion 2018.1.2
gcc-8.2
```

I want to use Clion to try the rocksdb. I add a new `CMakeLists.txt` file at examples directory.

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_subdirectory(examples)
```

**examples/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
add_executable(s_test simple_example.cc)
target_link_libraries(s_test ${LIBS})
```

But when I build the s_test executable, I get the error as follows.

```
Linking CXX shared library librocksdb.dylib
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"google::FlagRegisterer::FlagRegisterer<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(char const*, char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)", referenced from:
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in db_bench_tool.cc.o
  __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in trace_analyzer_tool.cc.o
"google::SetUsageMessage(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  rocksdb::db_bench_tool(int, char**) in db_bench_tool.cc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [librocksdb.5.17.0.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rocksdb-shared.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/s_test.dir/rule] Error 2
```

And I already installed the gflags previously.

```
ls /usr/local/lib | grep gflags

libgflags.2.2.1.dylib
libgflags.2.2.dylib
libgflags.dylib
libgflags_nothreads.2.2.1.dylib
libgflags_nothreads.2.2.dylib
libgflags_nothreads.dylib
```

How to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: I don't see **linking** with gflags in your code. Variable `LIBS` seems to be empty (not set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pull down the gflags package from git hub.  I also use CLION.

So, this is the procedure I followed to pull down rocksdb and gflags:

```
~> cd CLionProjects
~/CLionProjects> git clone git@github.com:facebook/rocksdb.git
~/CLionProjects> cd rocksdb
~/CLionProjects/rocksdb> git clone git@github.com:gflags/gflags.git
```

I then created gflagss.cmake at

`~/CLionProjects/rocksdb/cmake/modules`

with the following content:

```
# - Find GFLAGS

set(GFLAGS_ROOT_DIR ./gflags/cmake-build-debug)
find_path(GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES bzlib.h
  HINTS ${GFLAGS_ROOT_DIR}/include)

find_library(GFLAGS_LIBRARIES
  NAMES gflags
  HINTS ${GFLAGS_ROOT_DIR}/lib)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args(bzip2 DEFAULT_MSG BZIP2_LIBRARIES BZIP2_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(
  GFLAGS_LIBRARIES
  GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

I then opened the gflags folder in CLion and built glfags.

I then opened a separate CLion window/folder for rocksdb and built that.